# Is there a software that can screen share under Wayland?

Tags: skype, wayland

I've read that even screenshots may be a problem under Wayland. But I tested it in Sway, works perfectly (`grim -g "$(slurp)" - | wl-copy`).

The only problem is Skype. I can not show my screen. And the only solution I found was to switch to Xorg.

Is it a problem of Wayland? Or it's all right with Wayland and there are just no apps that can do that?

Answer (score 1):

I may be late but putting it here if someone else stumbles upon this thread.
You may try running skype on a browser(works edge only). That way you can share either your current screen or active window.
Not the perfect solution, I know. But gets the job done.